# The Terraform resource "random_pet" is not working

Tags: terraform

This code will create an EC2 instance with name `EC2 Instance`:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
}

module ec2 {
  source = "./ec2_instance"
  name = "EC2 Instance"
}
```

However, if I try and use the `random_pet` resource the Instance name becomes an empty string.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
}

resource "random_pet" "server" {
  length = 4
}

module ec2 {
  source = "./ec2_instance"
  name = "${random_pet.server.id}"
}
```

How come?

I'm using the `random_pet.server.id` code from https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/random/r/pet.html

UPDATE: by using an `output` I was able to debug this.
Terraform does not seem to show the value of this variable during a `plan`. However, when doing an `apply` it **did** successfully populate this variable (and therefore name the instance). The question then becomes `why does it not work in plan but does in apply`?

Comment: I think this is going to be difficult to answer without seeing your EC2 module. What happens if you replace the module with an output with a value of `"${random_pet.server.id}"`?

Comment: It wasn't anything to do with the module. I had the same behaviour when adding an output with that value. Updated the question...

Comment: Are you sure it's empty and not `"<computed>"`?

Comment: The value should be <computed>.